# How can i controll a 8x8 led-matrix display Max7219 with a raspberrypi in rust?

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi

I want to manually control every single dot on 4 together chained 8*8 led-matrices controlled by the max7219 microcontroller via the SPI interface.

I already hooked up the clock, master-output/slave-input and ChipSelect signal to my osciloscope and everything seems to work the way it should be.

But I am only able to get the display kind of working by sending random data to it and I do not know how that data gets encoded.

Here is the code

```
use rand::Rng;

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use spidev::{Spidev, SpidevOptions, SpidevTransfer, SpiModeFlags};

// Read the state of GPIO4 on a raspberry pi.  /dev/gpiochip0
// maps to the driver for the SoC (builtin) GPIO controller.
fn main() -> Result<(), gpio_cdev::Error> {
    let mut spi = create_spi().unwrap();
    write_spi(&mut spi);
    Ok(())
}

fn write_spi(spi: &mut Spidev) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    loop {
        let mut tx_buf = [0u8; 8];
        for i in 0..8 {
                tx_buf[i] = rng.gen_range(0..255);
        }

        spi.write(&tx_buf);
    }

    Ok(())
}


fn create_spi() -> io::Result<Spidev> {
    let mut spi = Spidev::open("/dev/spidev0.0")?;
    let options = SpidevOptions::new()
         .bits_per_word(8)
         .max_speed_hz(10_000)
         .mode(SpiModeFlags::SPI_MODE_0)
         .build();
    spi.configure(&options)?;
    Ok(spi)
}
```

What data must be sent to get it working?

Comment: Why not [use a library](https://github.com/bauerj/max7219). Else you would need to read the datasheet for that display and figure out the communications expected.

Comment: Oh yeah I found this: https://crates.io/crates/max7219 and the write_raw() function does exactly what I want.